# Jquery json echo

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

**EDIT**
Solved it. It was before the ajax call and, hence, this code. Thank you all for the answers.

---

I can't find anybody with this problem. I have a AJAX call to a PHP script that returns a JSON response.

I fetch the values from a database into an array:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($ret)){ 
    $temp = array(
     'id' => $row['id_reserva'], 
     'start' => $row['data_inicio'], 
     'end' => $row['data_fim'], 
     'title' => $row['descricao']
    );

    $js[] = $temp;
 }
```

Headers:

```
 header('Content-type: application/json');
```

And echo:

```
 echo json_encode($js);
```

There is no return whatsoever, just a null string.
What is really bugging me is that if instead of this I create a json string with the previous result directly in the code:

```
$temp = '[{"id":"3914", "start": "2011-08-25 09:00:00", 
"end":"2011-08-25 18:00:00", "title":"asdasdasd"},
{"id":"3915", "start": "2011-08-25 09:00:00", 
"end":"2011-08-25 18:00:00", "title":"asdasdasd"}]';

echo $temp;
```

It works.
Tried changing the file codification, comparing the strings, checking for some problem with chars, and nothing.

Anybody?

Cheers

Comment: Is your DB query actually working? If it's got an error or returning an empty result set, you'd get the empty json output.

Comment: @Marc B - yes, it's working. I used the generated result of the json_encode to create the string I echoed directly ($temp).

Comment: log HTTPrequest in chrome dev tools (right click in the console), and click on the conosole log link when the ajax call is actually done. It will open the request in a new tab, and you will see if there is a result and what it is (json will be displayed as "text")

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work. It tells me that the xhr finished loading (and the url of the script that provided the result), but nothing else.

Comment: @roselan - tried firefox firebug that has a xhr whatcher and the results: there's a call but it returns an empty string "[]".

Answer (score 2):

you have to encode it. try

```
echo json_encode($js);
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot about that in the display code. It's there, doesn't work with it.

Comment: json_encode is definitely in there.. did the author revise the question?

Comment: yes, yes I did. Replied to the comment. I forgot to put it in the code above.

Comment: @Alberto what version of php are you using? does it have json_encode enabled in it? can you output json using json_encode when you visit a test page in the browser?

Comment: Yeah, it works. I've tried also to generate the JSON string in the while block, instead of creating the array and encoding it. Still not working.

Comment: @Alberto Just for kicks, are you running `exit()` after the echo? If not try it.

Comment: @Ben - good one. Reminds me of flushing strings in C and JAVA. But, unfortunately, doesn't work either. I'm stuck. I'm thinking of some char in the string messing things up, but that would invalidate the json, and it's valid.

Comment: Can you try putting the query/json output on a separate page and navigating to it directly in the browser? At that point, use view souce(ctrl+u) and see if there are any extra lines or characters before or after the json. Also, copy paste the output into jsonlint.com to validate it.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm thinking, that must be something different in the string results. I've validated it and checked for differences in every possible way I could remember (including navigating it directly, view source, runned the strings through a few functions, htmlspecialchars, ut8_encode, etc), and still I can't pin point it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to json encode array:

```
echo json_encode($js);
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot about that in the display code. It's there, doesn't work with it.

Answer (score 1):

You're not outputting as JSON?

```
echo json_encode($js);
```

With your method, when jQuery gets the response and cannot parse the JSON it will return the empty string as you have experienced.

Comment: Sorry, forgot about that in the display code. It's there, doesn't work with it.

Answer (score 0):

Process of elimination..

- can you print_r ($js) and get output?
- Take out the header(); statement, does anything appear?
- Do you have error_reporting and display_errors turned on?
- You don't seem to initializing 'js' ($js = array()). If you get the literal string 'null' back, this could simply imply that your query is not returning any results.

I could add this statement to almost every long-winded PHP requestion on stack overflow:

Go through your code step by step and echo what you expect the contents of variables to be at that point. Then you'll slowly isolate exactly where your issue is; there's nothing wrong with your code as-is.

Comment: Done it all. To test it called the file directly with the two echos at the end, and they're exactly the same. Without header, same result, errors turned on yes. I've tried also to generate the JSON string in the while block, instead of creating the array and enconding it. No dice. I'm frustraded over this.

Comment: In that case try to reduce the code until you have something that we can run and test here. First start by taking out the mysql query. If I can run it locally, I can tell you where the issue lies.

Answer (score 0):

Are you not making a multi-dimentional array with `$js[] = $temp;` and then encoding that? Try just doing `json_encode($temp);`

Comment: Yeah, for each line it creates a row that merges into an array ($js[]). Using only $temp I'll get only the last result. Anyway, it doesn't work the same. It's very very strange.

Comment: Maybe try using the json_last_error function to see if it identifies anything?

Comment: I'm using jQuery(document).ajaxError(function(event, request, settings, err) for the error. Because it's an AJAX call after the document is loaded, and json_last_error is php function (runned before), it never presents any errors.